# VBA Look through List

Tags: vba, excel

I've got the following code which gets the word dividend from a column and then takes the whole row and copy pastes it to a new sheet.

```
Sub SortActions()
 Dim i&, k&, s$, v, r As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Set r = [index(a:a,match("###start",a:a,),):index(a:a,match("###end",a:a,),)].Offset(, 6)
    k = r.Row - 1
    v = r
    For i = 1 To UBound(v)
        If LCase$(v(i, 1)) = "dividend" Then
            s = s & ", " & i + k & ":" & i + k
        End If
    Next
    s = Mid$(s, 3)
    If Len(s) Then
        Set ws = ActiveSheet
        With Sheets.Add(, ws)
            ws.Range(s).Copy .[a1]
            Rows("1:1").Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Sheets("20140701_corporate_action_servi").Select
            Rows("2:2").Select
            Selection.Copy2
            Range("C32").Select
            Sheets("Sheet11").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Is there a way to make this dynamic. So if I want to search for more than word. For example if I have several rows with dividends and special dividends -> it would take all rows of dividends and all rows of special dividends and put them in separate sheets. I have tried ti with recording a macro it doesn't work as the words can differ. Maybe getting the content into a list would work. Please assist . Thanks

Comment: Why not just filter and copy the visible rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @Macro Man , I am submitting images of an example sheet and sheet after filter with a simple macro for filtering one field. Please all credit to @Macro Man, it is for illustration in a simple way.

[image: sample file]
[image]

Simple code as follows.

```
Sub Filter1Field()
    With Sheet1
          .AutoFilterMode = False
              With .Range("A1:H13")
                 .AutoFilter
                 .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="Dividend"
             End With
   End With
End Sub
```

*****UPDATE*******

If your other criteria such as "Sp. Dividend" is other field but on the same row as shown in the image appended and you wish to copy to other sheet you can use the code given below. Another image shows results obtained on sheet2. You can adopt the code to your requrements.

[image: sample 2]
[image: sample 2 after filter on sheet 2]

You can use this code:

```
Sub Test2()
     Dim LastRow As Long
    Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Offset(0).ClearContents
       With Worksheets("Sheet1")
         .Range("A1:H13").AutoFilter
         .Range("A1:H13").AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:="Dividend"
         .Range("A1:H13").AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:="=Sp. Dividend"
          LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
         .Range("A1:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy _
          Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
      End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Nant you can also use `Range("$A:$H")` for general range instead of fixed range like `Range("A1:H13")`